# Transferring tokens from account using web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, tokens

I created a contract token using the [sample solidity code tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/token). It has a function called transfer to send tokens between accounts:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
```

I need to now connect to this contract using web3, and then send a certain number of tokens generated to another account. I've been struggling with how to do this for quite some time and hoping this community could help. Here is what I have thus far...

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new 
web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io"));
var abi = [ {} ]

var account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount("0x12312312312323132312")

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi).at("0x282828288282828282")
contract.transferFrom('0xa121111211', '0xabbb2b2bb2', 100);
```

I know I am missing some piece of this. I am relatively new to solidity & web3 so apologies in advance for my ignorance regarding this matter. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the variable `abi` is empty when passed to the `eth.contract()` function.

Comment: @jojeyh, the abi is empty in the sample code for the purpose of this post. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?